# How can I move Macintosh HD out of container disk1?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I had partitioned my hard drive for Windows to be ran on it through Bootcamp. Everything was working okay, I could run in MacOSX or Windows. After I installed macOS High Sierra I began to have issues. When I was in Windows it would not find the MacOS disk. I was only able to load into OS by restarting Windows and holding down the 'option' key. 
I loaded MacOS, then deleted the Windows Partition. Now my disk looks like this:
[image: Disk Utility Screenshot]

My diskutil list reads:

[image: cmd disktuil list]

Macintosh HD is under a container disk, I have a bootcamp that cannot be used, and I have OSXRESERVED that I do not know what it is for. How can I delete OSXRESERVED, BOOTCAMP, and move Macintosh HD out of container disk1?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of misconceptions to clarify first:

- **It is correct that Macintosh HD is in a container**, since it is an APFS volume since High Sierra. This is the title of your question, so the answer is here first. It is not possible to move an APFS volume out of any container. It is correct that the startup volume, an APFS volume, is within an APFS container.
- It is correct that Windows cannot see Macintosh HD any more. Apple have not provided APFS drivers for Windows and the Boot Camp Control Panel cannot see Macintosh HD.

With that out of the way, we can deal with removing Boot Camp. Make sure you have a backup.

You should be able to **open Boot Camp Assistant and choose Remove Windows**.
This automates the process for you.

Alternatively with Disk Utility:

1. In Disk Utility, select APPLE SSD. Click the Partition button on the toolbar.
2. You should see a pie chart of the partitions on your disk. Select BOOTCAMP and click the – button to remove it from the pie. Repeat this for OSXRESERVED.
3. Expand the size of the container (Macintosh HD) to fill the rest of the disk, otherwise you will be left with free space not assigned to any partition.
4. Confirm that the rest of the disk partitions look correct, then choose Apply.